# Emulating a mobile screen size through an iframe

Tags: javascript, html, css

Just a random thought,
What if I wanted to showcase a responsive webdesign not by resizing the browser window, but actually loading the responsive site in an IFRAME having the same dimension as that of a mobile screen. Can this work?

assuming that I have an IFRAME

```
<iframe src="something" id="viewPort"/>
```

into which I load the responsive website. and then let the user test by adjusting the iframe width and height in their browser.

IF this can work it can be a boon for clients who don't know a thing about browsers.

Comment: Yes, it'd work, though I don't know if your clients would find 'resizing an iFrame' easier than 'resizing a browser'.

Comment: well i was just thinking of showing a desktop and a mobile view with just on click thats all hehe

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I win :) There is one, well known, you can either use or learn from.

http://mattkersley.com/responsive/

To be more specific, `iframe` absolutely does allow you to change `height` and `width` and its content does respond to that - that is to say - `@media` works.

Comment: This does not render the same as a mobile device. Mobile devices have viewport scaling while iframes do not. For example try loading pages.github.com on your phone, and then in an iframe above (scroll a bit down to the content).

Comment: This does NOT Emulate a mobile screen size through an iframe  as Tom points out.

Answer (score 8):

You could use the HTML property of iframe `seamless` and it's going to render on the width that you provide, like this for an iPad:

`<iframe src="yourURL" seamless width="768" height="1024"></iframe>`

Also if you wanna use it in XHTML documents, because attribute minimization is forbidden you will need to define it as `<iframe seamless="seamless">`.

**EDIT:**
Unfortunately, according to [w3schools](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_iframe_seamless.asp) the seamless attribute is removed and the browsers don't support it anymore.

Comment: This `seamless` attribute has been removed from HTML5 and is not supported anymore by any web browser.

Comment: I had an EDIT 4 years ago in which I specified that is/will be deprecated.

Comment: The edit says it is depreciated, now it it removed. The edit says you were still able to use it back then, now it doesn't work in any major web browser.

Answer (score 0):

What you propose should work, assuming you don't have anything else screwy like the child intentionally grabbing CSS from the parent etc.

Something like Firefox's responsive design view is designed for exactly what you are talking about too:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools/Responsive_Design_View

It's not hard to use, but I guess harder than just telling your client to "click here".