# Displaying a mobile version of responsive component without resizing the browser window

Tags: javascript, response

Making a document for the designers that displays the desktop and mobile examples of each visual component in a style library.  Client wants to see the examples of each on the page at the same time.

Currently doing this by putting it in an iframe, similar to [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22776725/emulating-a-mobile-screen-size-through-an-iframe).  Unfortunately the iframe solution is causing odd complications and side-effects.

**I was wondering if theres a better/simpler way I can tell the container of the mobile example to use the mobile breakpoint media queries?**

Comment: Maybe ask the client to make use of the browser's "device toolbar" (F12 -> Ctrl+Shift+M on Chrome)

Comment: @Jeff Wish it was that easy!  They are resistant to any and all technology they don't understand, even something as simple as that.

Comment: You could ask them to load the page here? http://www.mobilephoneemulator.com/